# Drupal 7: Three MainMenuItems with subitems, how to add special Template for every MainMenuItem incl. all subitems?

Tags: templates, drupal, path, nodes

currently i am working on a drupal site, which will have three main menu items, where each item will have several submenu items.

I want to assign a template for each main menu item, lets call it "section", which also applies to any submenuitem of that mainmenuitem.

The path in Drupal ist like node/1 for the first mainmenu item. I assigned URL Aliases for every subitem but i can not access them with template files.

For Example:

i can assign a template to node/1 with node--1.tpl.php but node/7 is a submenu item and this node is logically not affected.

Would be very thankful for an advice, greetings from germany :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make use of content types for this one.
Each menu item and its submenu items will share a content type.
When you create the new nodes choose their content type according to menu they will be in.

After you do that, you can theme them using:
node--CONTENT-TYPE-MACHINE-NAME.tpl.php

About creating and using custom content types:
https://drupal.org/node/774728